# What does "isomorphism" exactly refer to in topology?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am reading an article and I came across the sentence that states as below:

"A linear separating **isomorphism** from $C(T)$ onto $C(S)$ is continuous, in which $C(S)$ and $C(T)$ denote sup-normed Banach spaces of real or complex-valued continuous
functions on the compact Hausdorff spaces $S$ and $T$, respectively."

The writer has used only the **injectivity** and **surjectivity** properties to prove the theorem, so it has made me think that the isomorphism mentioned above is the same as a **bijection map**.
On the other hand, I have been used to seeing isomorphisms in Algebra. Is there anything more than this with the word isomorphism in the sentence above?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: An isomorphism in this context is a linear bijection.

Comment: An isomorphism is supposed to be a bijection that preserves the relevant structure. I think in topology an isomorphism is a bijection $f$ between topological spaces with the property that $A$ is open if and only if $f(A)$ is open. Equivalently, an isomorphism of topological spaces is a bijection $f$ between topological spaces such that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are both continuous. In other words, a homeomorphism. However, a "linear separating isomorphism" as mentioned in the passage you quoted is probably something different.

Comment: The result that OP has stated says continuity is a consequence of some other properties. So continuity is not part of the assumption. @littleO

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a link to the article.

Comment: Me too. The result is very interesting.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you so much, here is the link. [link] (https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-mathematical-bulletin/article/automatic-continuity-of-separating-linear-isomorphisms)/C4DC3971593FF96D98367CC2B1EBEF81

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: thank you! I put the link. @littleO

Comment: Linearity is used; so isomorphism is in the sense of (abstract) vector spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Well isomorphism in the topology (or more correctly in the category of topological spaces) are homeomorphisms. That is if we have two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, then saying that $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic is exactly the same as saying $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic.

Now since we are working with Banach spaces (which are topological spaces themselves), there is a theorem in *Functional Analysis* called the open mapping theorem:

> *Open Mapping Theorem:* If $X$ and $Y$ are Banach Spaces, then any continuous surjective linear map $L : X \to Y$ is an open map.

Now if we have the added property that $L$ is an injective map, which is what it seems like the author is asserting, then we obtain a continous bijective open map, from the open mapping theorem.

Now going back to topology, there is a nice lemma that one can prove.

> *Lemma:* Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces. If $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous, bijective open map, then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Putting all this together one can see that this lemma along with the open mapping theorem shows that we have an homeomorphism.

---

$^*$For sets, isomorphisms are bijections.

Comment: This is fine for the question in the title. But I don't think you read the question properly.